# How to build 64-bit OCaml 3.10.0 on windows

Tags: cygwin, ocaml

I've an executable that is compiled using OCaml 3.10.0 (ocaml-3.10.0-win-mgw.exe) which runs into some capacity issue because it's 32-bit. I want to compile it as a 64-bit executable and I tried compiling it with the most recent version of OCaml (4.0.7) but I ran into bunch of errors because the library I use are built using 3.10.0. I don't know how to rebuild my libraries in 4.0.7 and I don't want to.

All I want to know is how to compile OCaml 3.10.0 in 64 bit so that I can compile my program to generate a 64-bit executable. I used cygwin32 and followed the installation steps:

```
./configure
make world
make opt
make opt.opt
make install
```

However, this still installs the 32 bit version. I used cygwin64, but it still failed and produced the following error while compiling ocamlrun.exe

```
gcc -DCAML_NAME_SPACE -O -fno-defer-pop -Wall -U_WIN32 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT   -c -o prims.o prims.c
gcc -fno-defer-pop -Wall -U_WIN32 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT  -o ocamlrun.exe \
      prims.o libcamlrun.a -lm   -lpthread
libcamlrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x26d): undefined reference to `setmode'
libcamlrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x26d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `setmode'
libcamlrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x295): undefined reference to `setmode'
libcamlrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0x295): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `setmode'
libcamlrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0xa77): undefined reference to `setmode'
libcamlrun.a(io.o):io.c:(.text+0xa77): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `setmode'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why not use Cygwin 64 that also has Ocaml https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/ocaml/ocaml-4.04.2-1 ?

Comment: I have old libraries that was compiled using OCaml 3.10.0, I have to rebuild them using the new version of OCaml.

Comment: If you are changing from 32 to 64 bit you need to recompile all anyway. The cygwin gcc compiler produces cygwin programs, while your `ocaml-3.10.0-win-mgw.exe` seems a mingw program. Eventually you can compile from a cygwin 64 with the `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core` cross-compiler

Comment: After multiple trials, I managed to build OCaml 3.10.0 on windows7 using msvc64. However, It seems that the resulted ocaml compilers are only for windows, I have to build it again on Unix which I didn't have any luck with it so far.

Can I cross compile on windows to generate ocaml compilers for both platforms ? Maybe using ./configure with a target option? Also would msvc64 work for that or I have to use mingw64?